# Jenkins slackSend pretty url

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, slack, slack-api

I am using the jenkins slack notification plugin inside a pipeline. Inside that pipeline I've got several

```
slackSend (color: colorCode, message: message)
```

I am also posting several links sometimes which show up fully extended on slack: `http://ec2-......eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

How should I format the message I send so that it acts as an anchor tag (having a name, which directs to url as soon as it's clicked?)

Comment: Do you mean named url? try this `<http://ec2-......eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com|ec2 url>`? See [message formating](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls)

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko exactly, do you mind posting as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `<url|name>` syntax to do this.
For example `<http://ec2-......eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com|ec2 url>`
See [Linking to URLs](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls) for more information.