# Jenkins slackSend pretty url not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, slack

I want Jenkins to send a message to Slack containing a URL. I already have other text as URL's already by following the same info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794363/jenkins-slacksend-pretty-url)

However, I am seeing my message have the wrong format and not putting my text as a link. I have a suspicion that the link might be too long (but I can't find any docs to say this might be the case) or that I am using a `.stripMargin()` and it is interfering somehow (this is less likely as the other links are working)

[image: My Slack message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

On the Slack documentation, it gives you this warning:

"URLs with spaces will break, so we recommend that you remove any spaces from your URL links."

I am generating my link by returning the standard output of a shell command in my Jenkins script. Something like this:

```
String myGeneratedUrl = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws s3 presign s3://bucketName/objectname")
```

Now I'm not sure what happens in Jenkins when you return the standard output of a shell command, but I'm pretty sure it has a whitespace in it somewhere, presumably at the start or the end. To avoid this, I needed to `.trim()` the value that is returned by the the sh() script so it looks like this:

```
String myGeneratedUrl = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws s3 presign s3://bucketName/objectname").trim()
```

Now my link in Jenkins works!